# NASM 80387 coprocessor printf printing -nan

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

This is nasm program in which I am trying to calculate roots of a quadratic equation. I am using printf and scanf. After all the calculation, when I am printing the two roots which are stored in variables root1 and root2, the values for both which are being printed is -nan. What could be the problem in the program. 'write' and 'exit' macros are being included from other files.

```
extern printf
extern scanf

section .data
msg1 db "enter a: "
len1 equ $-msg1
msg2 db "enter b: "
len2 equ $-msg2
msg3 db "enter c: "
len3 equ $-msg3

frmt1 db "%lf",0
frmt2 db "the numbers are :- ",10,"a = %lf",10,"b = %lf",10,"c = %lf",10,0
frmt3 db "root1 = %lf",10,0
frmt4 db "root2 = %lf",10,0

num4 dq 4
num2 dq 2

section .bss
a resq 1
b resq 1
c resq 1
del resq 1
sdel resq 1
root1 resq 1
root2 resq 1

section .code
global main
main:
;create stack frame
push rbp
mov rbp,rsp

write msg1,len1
mov rdi,frmt1
mov rsi,a
call scanf

write msg2,len2
mov rdi,frmt1
mov rsi,b
call scanf

write msg3,len3
mov rdi,frmt1
mov rsi,c
call scanf

mov rdi,frmt2
movq xmm0,[a]
movq xmm1,[b]
movq xmm2,[c]
mov rax,3
call printf

finit   ;initilaize coprocessor
fld qword[b]
fmul qword[b]
fld qword[a]
fmul qword[c]
fimul word[num4]
fsub
fst qword[del]
fsqrt
fstp qword[sdel]
fld qword[b]
fchs
fadd qword[sdel]
fild word[num2]
fmul qword[a]
fdiv 
fstp qword[root1]
fld qword[b]
fchs
fsub qword[sdel]
fld qword[a]
fimul word[num2]
fdiv
fstp qword[root2]

mov rdi,frmt3
movq xmm0,[root1]
mov rax,1
call printf

mov rdi,frmt4
movq xmm0,[root2]
mov rax,1
call printf



;destroy stack frame
mov rsp,rbp
pop rsp
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not handling the condition for imaginary roots in this case. Hence I am getting the values of root1 and root2 as -nan. If I enter the values of a,b,c such that b^2-4ac >= 0, the answer comes out fine.